# How can I group static methods in a class in a clean way

Tags: java, static-methods

I would like to expose a bunch of general usage static methods in JSF in an application scoped bean. Now my code is as follows:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class StaticUtils{

     public static void bla(){ ... }

     public static void blabla(MyParam param){ ... }

     public static void bla2(){ ... }

     public static void blabla2(MyParam param){ ... }

     ...
}
```

The thing is that my bean is growing too much and I have methods that don't have to do with each other. Therefore I was thinking of grouping them together by functionality and extracting them into other classes. Afterwards I would, by composition, have an instance of each class in the aforementioned ApplicationScopedBean and access to the static methods I grouped through a wrapper method.

```
public class A{

     public static void bla(){ ... }

     public static void blabla(MyParam param){ ... }

     ...
}

public class B{

     public static void bla2(){ ... }

     public static void blabla2(MyParam param){ ... }

     ...
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class StaticUtils{

     public static void bla(){ A.bla(); }

     public static void blabla(MyParam param){ A.blabla(param); }

     public static void bla2(){ B.bla2(); }

     public static void blabla2(MyParam param){ B.blabla2(param); }

 }
```

As multiple inheritance is directly not available in java, and neither want I to use multilevel inheritance nor @ApplicationScoped for all the resulting beans, is there a better/cleaner/less verbose way to do it? Can I automatically expose all public methods from inner objects in a class, in such a way that I can make its code more or less as short as this?

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class StaticUtils{

   private A a;

   private B b;

   ...
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: No, you can't. There are several things you could do however:

- You could use one interface for every functional class and have both your `A`, `B` or whatever and your `StaticUtils` implement each of these interfaces. Then in the `StaticUtils` class you can have something like

  ```
  public static void bla() {
      A.bla();
  }
  ```
- If these functions are all static you can actually use static imports, no need for a bean:

  ```
  import static org.bla.A.bla;
  import static org.bla.B.*;
  // etc.
  ```
- You want to use beans then you could have several (`A`, `B`, ...) rather than just the `StaticUtils` class. If the functions are not connected that is probably the cleanest solution.
- You can do what Predrag Maric suggested and just hold instances of `A`, `B` and so on as public members in the `StaticUtils` class.

Comment: First of all thanks for the proposals:

- Pedrag, that would fit if I could change the calls in the xhtml code, but there is a lot of code that is not under my supervision relying on the same backend, that is why I want to keep the call the same:

    <h:outputText value="#{bean.propValue}" title="#{staticUtils.blabla(bean.propValue)/>

- blalasaadri I agree that programming with interfaces is the cleanest solution but also too verbose, since I want to have only a big sack with small bags of utility methods. They are in a bean in order to be called with EL as the example I wrote above.

Comment: @DavidP If you can't change the XHTML then I'm afraid you'll be left with a verbose solution which ever solution you choose. The design of the calls won't allow for anything else.

Comment: I agree with @blalasaadri, that is quite a limitation. You probably won't find anything cleaner that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
public class StaticUtils{

   public static A a;

   public static B b;

   ...
 }
```

That way, you could access, for example, A's methods like `StaticUtils.a.bla()`?

Comment: Probably these members would even be `final`, otherwise they could be changed in the bean (which probably isn't wanted).

Comment: I agree, but the focus was on visibility and class structure